# DevDemon Forms - form:error:required_error

Tags: error, forms, devdemon

When setting fields to Required and testing the form submission, I noticed the text **form:error:required_field** shows up. Is there a way to change the text to something else? I want it to just say Required Field or Value is Required. Thanks!

[image: form error - required field]

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Modules -> Forms -> Settings and make sure you have messages in there. Then click Save. If you updated from an older version, these might not be saved.